# How do I use the /give command to give myself a broken elytra?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to use the `/give` command to give myself a broken elytra. So far I have `/give @p elytra 1 0 {"Broken":1}` but that doesn't work. It then says

```
Component 'Broken' was not an object.
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @Frank Added more detail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quick solution: `/give @p elytra 1 431`

Long explanation:

The syntax of the `/give` command is the following:

```
give <player: target> <itemName: string> [amount: int] [data: int] [components: components]
```

([from the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/give), [archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands/give&oldid=1264822))

`player` is a target selector, in your case you want @p, meaning the nearest player to you, which is yourself.

`itemName` is the name of the item, that's `elytra`.

`amount` is the number of items you want to have, since `/give` requires at least 1 and the stack limit of elytra is 1, only 1 is possible.

`data` is the so-called "metadata" of the item. The primary use of it and the reason it was originally added was for uses of an items. Since the durability of the elytra (0 or not) decides if it is broken, you can just set it to 431 to have a 0 durability elytra. (Or 432, I have two conflicting sources, just try it.)

`components` is optional and you don't need it in this case. And since you're playing PE and not Java, you could only use "CanPlaceOn" (which is useless, because elytra can't be placed) and "CanDestroy" (which you don't want) anyway.

Comment: I believe it is 431, since a broken elytra is supposed to be stuck at 1 durability until repaired.

Comment: Never mind. Both ways work.

Comment: Then it's actually 431. Making the metadata higher doesn't change the damage value (it stays at 0). Btw, I wrote this whole answer without starting Minecraft once. ;)

Comment: Both 431 and 432 work. For some reason the texture the broken elytra isn't showing up (nothing is showing up in the inventory) but that's probably a bug. Thanks!

Comment: Also @s is not available in PE.

Answer (score -1):

if you are playing in one of the newer versions it is now:

```
/give @p minecraft:elytra{Damage:431} 1
```

Comment: Hello! What do you mean by "newer versions"? Since which version?

Comment: My question was about Bedrock Edition and there is [currently no NBT](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/334104/188492) as far as I know.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a quick one:

```
/give (your mc name) elytra
```